# Is it possible to do this in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a regular table called `TABLE1` with a column `NUMBER(8)` and a column `varchar2(100)`.

Now I've created an `OBJECT TYPE` `T_MYTYPE`with two attributes: one `NUMBER` and another `varchar2`.

In a nutshell, they are exactly the same.

Now I want to do the following.

```
v_obj T_MYTYPE;

begin 
 select * into v_obj from TABLE1 t1 where t1.num = 9;--guaranteed to return only ONE row!!
end;
```

but **PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values**..

This is quite frustrating... I just want to be able to return **ONE** row of data into a collection!! Be it a RECORD or a OBJECT TYPE!!, I don't care... I just can't seem to make this work..!!!! Can anyone help??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can.  You just need to use the object constructor

```
SQL> create type t_simple_emp
  2      as object
  3  (
  4    empno number,
  5    ename varchar2(100)
  6  );
  7  /

Type created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_simple_emp t_simple_emp;
  3  begin
  4    select t_simple_emp( empno, ename )
  5      into l_simple_emp
  6      from emp
  7     where ename = 'KING';
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

In your case, it would be

```
SELECT t_mytype( column1, column2 )
  INTO v_obj
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE t1.num = 9;
```

If all you want to do is select an entire row from a table into a record type, however, then you'd want to do as ruakh suggested and just declare a `%ROWTYPE` record

```
declare
  l_emp_rec emp%rowtype;
begin
  select *
    into l_emp_rec
    from emp
   where ename = 'KING';
end;
/
```

Comment: I just read a full book on PLSQL and I didn't see this... Perhaps I missed it... Too bad I'll only be able to test it on monday when I get back to work...

Comment: Come to think of it.. This is rather counter-intuitive is it not?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida - If you just want to select all the columns of a table into a record rather than selecting subsets of columns or doing anything that requires an object type, ruakh's suggestion of declaring a `%ROWTYPE` collection would be preferrable.

Comment: If I'm not wrong I think that, when trying the second approach ruakh has suggested, I ran into a *can't access a variable that's marked for delete* error message. DOes that make sense? Like I said, I can only check this  on monday when I get back to work.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida - That doesn't make sense.  That error sounds like you're trying to use a collection that is declared in PL/SQL, not SQL, in a SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
v_obj T_MYTYPE;
```

Try this:

```
v_obj table1%ROWTYPE;
```

to declare it as having the exact same type as a row of `table1`.

Comment: But then won't I have to use `table` and `cast` operands? I shied away from using records because I read that we could only use `cast` with types create via `CREATE TYPE foo....` .. I tried to use RECORDs before using OBJECT TYPEs but I couldn't `SELECT INTO` because of the problem I just described.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida: There are certainly advantages and disadvantages to this approach. One of its advantages is that it's the simplest approach; another is that it very faithfully represents a row of a table. You wrote, "I just want to be able to return ONE row of data into a collection!! Be it a RECORD or a OBJECT TYPE!!, I don't care...", so I thought that those advantages would outweigh the disadvantages for you. If they don't, then by all means, you don't have to use this approach. :-)

Comment: I think I did try your approach.I can't remember but I think I came across another problem... I'll check it first thing on monday and then come back to say what happened.